# AppleScript - exclude certain files when duplicating a folder from one location to another

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript that is working to duplicate the contents of a source folder to a destination folder. I now need to add some conditional logic to this so that it excludes certain files from the source folder and doesn't copy across all files/folders.

Here's my current script:

```
set here to POSIX file "/Users/benny/Desktop/Projects/Source/Project1"
set there to POSIX file "/Users/benny/Documents/Masters"

tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to duplicate ¬
             every item in the folder here to there
```

I would like to add some logic so that it doesn't copy across these files:

```
Import.log
Recover.log
```

Haven't tried to get the syntax working here but haven't been able to work out how to exclude files by their filename so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `duplicate` *command* is wrapped in a `try` *statement* because it will error out if *items* of the same *name* already exist in `there`. You could uncomment the `with replacing` and get rid of the `try` *statement*, that is if replacing an existing *item* is okay.

```applescript
set here to POSIX file "/Users/benny/Desktop/Projects/Source/Project1"
set there to POSIX file "/Users/benny/Documents/Masters"

tell application id "com.apple.Finder"
    set theseItems to a reference to ¬
        (items whose name is not equal to "Import.log" and ¬
            name is not equal to "Recover.log") of folder here
    try
        duplicate theseItems to there -- with replacing
    end try
end tell
```

Comment: Nice.  For interested readers, _Finder_ is one of the few scriptable applications that permit `whose` filters to perform comparisons for a single property against a specified list of values. So, one is permitted to do this: `...whose name is not in {"Import.log", "Recover.log"}...`. It can be very useful on occasion.